# Batch renaming files to remove specific characters

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename, batch-processing, batch-rename

How can I create a batch file that removes specific characters from the filenames only? Is it possible to do in a script? I'm looking to remove these symbols:

```
({[}])+-
```

Comment: Most of what you have written is irrelevant to what you actually want; I suggest that you remove the waffle and simply ask *"How do I batch rename a group of files by removing individual characters in the set `({[}])+-`?"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me introduce you to [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), a scripting language far more powerful and easier to learn than the M$ alternative Powershell. The windows interpreter you can find at http://rubyinstaller.org/
I could give you the code in one line but for clarity here a 4 line program that does what you need.

```
Dir['c:/temp/*.package'].each do |file|
  new_name = File.basename(file.gsub(/[({\[}\])+-]/, ''))
  File.rename(file, new_name)
end
```

Let me explain, the Dir command enumerates the path with wildcards inside, in unix notation with slashes instead of backslashes and for each file it generates a new_name by taking the basename (filename only) of the path and using a Regular Expression to replace (gsub) the characters inside the /[]/ with the second parameter, '' (empty string). Regular Expressions are the way to go for such things, plenty of information to google if you want to know more about.
Finally I use the utility class File (yes Ruby is totally Object Oriented) to rename the file to the new name.

You could do this with any language but I bet not so concise and readable as in Ruby. Install the Ruby interpreter, save these lines in eg cleanup.rb, change the path to yours and fire it up with `ruby cleanup`, or just `cleanup` if your extension is correctly associated.

This renames

```
c:\temp\na({[}])+-me.package
```

to

```
c:\temp\name.package
```

And as a bonus: here the one line version that does the same in the current folder.

```
Dir['*'].each {|f| File.rename(f, File.basename(f.gsub(/[({\[}\])+-]/, '')))}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Windows cmd.exe command shell's rename command lacks the power to do what you need.  It can be done with the PowerShell [Rename-Item](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315353.aspx) command using the `-Replace` operator with a regular expression.

However running PowerShell scripts is restricted by security policies, so it is [not quite as straightforward](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/running-powershell-scripts-easy-1-2-3) as a cmd batch script.  A scripting language such as Python may be less problematic.

Comment: Ruby is the easier path vs Python, surely if you only have experience with batch

Comment: @peter : Quite possibly so; I only said "such as" - I know neither language particularly well - it was just an example.  I would personally do  it in C++ just because that is the language I know best and use daily so it would be faster.  The best language for quick jobs is often the one you know already, or the one for which you have installed tools, rather than necessarily the best suited to the task.

Comment: You are so right. But that doesn't play in the case of the OP, the easier and comprehendable the better I would think.

Answer (score 0):

The Output

```
 C:\Users\User>(
 Set FName=test()[]{}+-
 Set FName=!Fname:(=!
 Set FName=!Fname:)=!
 Set FName=!Fname:{=!
 Set FName=!Fname:}=!
 Set FName=!Fname:[=!
 Set FName=!Fname:]=!
 Set FName=!Fname:+=!
 Set FName=!Fname:-=!
 Echo Ren test()[]{}+-.asc !Fname!.*
)
Ren test()[]{}+-.asc test.*
```

The batchfile

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%A in (*.asc) Do (
Set FName=%%~nA
Set FName=!Fname:^(=!
Set FName=!Fname:^)=!
Set FName=!Fname:{=!
Set FName=!Fname:}=!
Set FName=!Fname:[=!
Set FName=!Fname:]=!
Set FName=!Fname:+=!
Set FName=!Fname:-=!
Echo Ren %%A !Fname!.*
)
```